# Laravel get latest record with orderBy and join

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

i want to get latest record with joinung 2 tables. but in my below code i get error:

Query builder:

```
$latestJournal = DB::table('journals')
                            ->join('journalslists',function($join){
                                $join->on('journalslists.journalCategory', '=', 'journals.id');
                            })
                            ->order_by('journals.id', 'desc')->first();
```

MySql Command ( i need to this command ) :

```
SELECT *
FROM `journals`
INNER JOIN `journalslists` ON `journalslists`.`journalCategory` = `journals`.`id`
ORDER BY journals.id DESC
LIMIT 1
```

i get this error:

```
BadMethodCallException

Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::order_by()
```

Comment: dude.... `orderBy`.... see the docs 1st -_-

Answer (score 3):

The exception tells you whats the problem: the order_by method is undefined, the correct method is orderBy. Here is a example based on Laravel query builder docs:

```
$users = DB::table('users')
                ->orderBy('name', 'desc')
                ->get();
```

More on laravel documentation: http://laravel.com/docs/queries#selects

Comment: this is not my quastion.

Comment: TuxWorld whats your question?

Answer (score 0):

```
$latestJournal = DB::table('journals')
                 ->join('journalslists','journalslists.journalCategory', '=','journals.id');
                 ->order_by('journals.id', 'desc')
                 ->first();
```